# Can not get 5.1 sound over S/PDIF to my Onkyo anymore

Tags: windows-7, audio, 5.1, spdif

I was reading for days now to find a solution for my problem but i didnt found one.

I set up my computer new and installed windows 7 64bit again. Before that everything went fine. But right now I am not able to get any 5.1 Sound from my computer over S/PDIF to my Onkyo 5.1 System. 
I installed the newest version of Realtek Audio HD. But when i open the Realtek Audio HD Manager I cant choose the option to set 5.1 Speakers. It only shows me a stereo system. But if I test DTS or Dolby for my Realtek Digital Output over windows it works perfektly.

Can someone please help me? I am always watching movies over my computer and only get 2.1 Sound now...

Thanks alot!